# Disable tab-identing in Notepad++ till bringing them back

Tags: notepad++, tabs

Say I don't want tab indents at all, from any kind, in Notepad++. I want Notepad++ to:

1. Not letting me insert tab indents until I bring these back.
2. Automatically transform all tab indents whatsoever to spaced, until I disable that functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I don't want tab indents at all

1. Go to menu -> "Preferences"
2. Click "Language" on the left side
3. In the "Tab Setting" area on the right hand side

   - Set "Tab size" as appropriate
   - Enable "Replace by space"

     [image]
4. Click "Close"

Comment: Yes found that this morning and forgot to answer... Oh man, you preceded me. Gladly accepting and give a thumb up! I hope users will enjoy this!